# windows phone 7 device compatibility

Tags: windows-phone-7

I noticed windows phone 7 only has one hardware standard now.
I just wonder if the compatibilities of wp7 devices provided by different hardware vendors are better than the complex and headache android devices?

Welcome any comment

Comment: If i'm not mistaken Microsoft has some tough standards for the hardware of devices, it definetely be a better situation than android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft's standards for the WP7 make it so that app compatibility is now solid (unlike past version of WinMo).  If you have an app that runs on one phone, it will run on them all.

Comment: but I also noticed there will be a possible low cost model of screen size 320*480 which is different from current 480*800. i hope to know if it is true?

Comment: Yes, the specs say that 320x480 is valid.  There are no devices out (yet anyway) with that resolution, but you still shouldn't hard code your app for 480x800.

Answer (score 0):

When the original specs came out it was intended that there would be 2 chassis specs. The first with a screen resolution of 480x800 and another, coming later, with a resolution of 320x480.

Since the Nokia deal it is very unlikely that devices with a 320x480 screen, and other features as previously described, will now be released. Other chassis specs are expected but we'd only be guessing at what these would be.

The current templates include hard coded margins, etc. which are appropriate for the 480x800 resolution. Until we know what, if any other resolutions the platform will support it's not known if just hard coded values will still be appropriate.

The most recent recommendations I've had from the WP7 development and design teams are to focus purely on the 800x480 resolution devices and worry about other resolutions as and when they're announced.
It has been suggested that if devices with smaller screens are released then the framework will include the ability to automatically scale the apps/pages for such resolutions. I imagine there will also be the ability to adjust the sceen design based on the resolution but this is currently just a guess. If other resolutions don't support the same ratios then this will be particularly important.

To do anything else, before details of what other resolutions may need to be supported is additional work for now and is based purely on guesswork. I'd recommend following the advice and just sticking to creating apps which are designed for 480x800. If and when the need to support other resolutions arises we can worry about how best to do so then.